# Why array does not set using useState in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to set array using useState feature

```
function SelectCategoryList() {
        const [presentDataArray, setPresentDataArray] = useState([]);
        const hello = ['hello', 'bye'];

        useEffect(() => {
            console.log(hello);
            setPresentDataArray([...hello]);
            console.log(presentDataArray);
        }, []);
}

first console : ['hello', 'bye']
second console : []
```

Why presentDataArray does not set value by `helloArray`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately
refer this ,you will get you answer of console

Comment: same like setState useState is not synchronous , so after setting the value you cant view the value immediately . Move the console to the return method and check

Comment: @pageNotfoUnd What do you mean that 'Move the console to the return method and check'?

Comment: How to log the data only once which is updated in useEffect. @KishanJaiswal

Comment: @RayKim place the console inside the return function of your component to check the updated state value

Comment: @pageNotfoUnd It works!! Thank you very much. I didn't understand at all about this and manage to figure out how to log this value in my head. Thank you.